# Wordpress - Passing Variable to Custom Post Type Archive

Tags: wordpress

I am using /%postname%/ permalinks and want to be able to pass a variable to my custom post type archive. My goal is to have the archive receive a value which I use to sort the individual posts. My overall goal is essentially fake 'categories' by assigning the custom posts a meta value and sorting using the value I pass through the url.

A more literal Example:

example.com/vegetables/

is the path to my custom post type archive. I want to be able to direct users to this path:

example.com/vegetables/potatoes

and in the template be able to pull "potatoes" from the query string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just use categories?  Then wordpress does all the heavy lifting.  Seems like you are reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: Nope the site uses custom taxonomies for several different post types with multiple relationship aspects, so Wordpresses category system is inadequate for slicing and dicing it all.